# Cocos2d 2.0: I get a higher memory allocation peak setting default pixel format to kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am getting kind of crazy. I got an AppDelegate from where I lunch an Introduction Scene. I used TexturePacker to get a plist and png file **using RGBA4444 pixel format** and set in XCode to **"NO" for the option to "compress PNG files"** in order to preserve the optimized files.

My AppDelegate is configured with a default pixel format of kEAGLColorFormatRGB565:

```
 CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

Scenario 1: I run my AppDelegate and push the Introduction scene **without changing the default pixel format** (in other words, leaving the default AppDelegate settings) and get the following Allocation analysis. The blue peak corresponds to a **16 MB memory allocation** in the IntroductionScene when creating the first CCSprite frame from the plist file  (the blue peak corresponds to 16 MB, I couldn't take a better screenshot with the values displayed, the rest corresponds to about 2MB of memory allocated - sorry).

[image: First case]

Scenario 2: I set the default pixel format to **kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444** in the IntroBackgroundScene (as below).

```
@implementation IntroBackgroundScene

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Intro background.plist"];
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Intro background 0.png"];
        background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
        background.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, 0.0f);
        [self addChild:background];

        foreground = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Intro background 1.png"];
        foreground.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
        foreground.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, 0.0f);
        [self addChild:foreground z:2];
```

This gives me a peak of **26 MB of memory usage** (even if the pixel format settings is set to **kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444**). See below (the blue peak corresponds to 26 MB, I couldn't take a better screenshot with the values displayed - sorry):

[image: Second case]

**I thought that it would have reduced the memory allocation and not increased. Why is this?**

Secondly, why the memory allocation peaks to whatever number (16/26MB) and then gets down to 2MB? I was expecting it to be always 2MB as I am using optimized texture sheets.

Here is the TexturePacker build settings:

[image: Texture packer]

I am building for Cocos2d and using a 2048*2048 pixels sheet with RGBA4444 activated. It should consume only 2 bytes per pixel for a total of about 8 MB. **I don't understand why memort allocation peaks to 16 MB in the IntroBackground init method and why it then goes down to only 2MB (and not 8 MB).**

Any insight on how to analyze and understand this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Texture dumb info from iPod touch 4th gen:**

cocos2d: "Intro background.png" rc=7    id=3    2048 x 2048 @ 32 bpp => 16384 KB
cocos2d: CCTextureCache dumpDebugInfo:  2 textures, for 16448 KB (16.06 MB)

It looks like that all frames in a texture sheet are temporarily loaded in memory. Is this normal? **Is there any way to avoid this? (this might cause memory leaks when loading scens with multiple sheets)**

Comment: i wrote a little something here regarding your 2 Mb.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560405/memory-warnings-in-cocos2d-box2d-apps-on-device-iphone-ipad/14564610#14564610

Comment: If you really want to get a sense of how much memory is consumed by your various graphic object, use     [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thanks. I get 2 textures for a total of 16MB of memory used, which corresponds to the two textures of 640*960 each in the Introduction background.plist file. I am trying to make sense of your answer. From what you say those images get "cached" on load but afterwards get removed. So there should be no way to avoid this high memory allocation peaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be (to explain the peak) that the app has 1) to load the zipped data stream in core, 2) unzip in core ... thus holding both the zipped and unzipped plus ancillary objects used in the process ... then when the memory block is passed to the GPU, the memory is released (and the texture's memory requirement is discounted from the main process) ... assuming that trace was taken on a device. The simulator does not make use of the host's GPU, thus taking the same trace on simulator would show a much higher memory foot print, that includes the textures' memory requirements.

Comment: Yeah, the trace is taken on a real device (iPod touch 4th gen). I am not really sure what you refer for "zipped data", and I am not aware where I could be using it exepct when I use plist and png files for the Introduction background sprite sheet. So basically for a certain time all textures in a spritesheet are loaded in the GPU memory block causing the memory to peak?

Comment: ah ... i thought you were using .pvr.gz output format from texture packer (i would, much faster load on devices, leaner textures, possibly even avoid the peak ... as per the traces i showed in that other post).

Comment: Actually, they are held in main process memory until they are processed to a format that consumable by the PowerVR GPU. So if you use pvr output format, it is immediately useable by the graphic processor, thus it goes from disk to processor very rapidly.

Comment: thanks man :)! I tried using pvr.ccz (not gz) and it decreases the memory peak to 10 MB and the texture dump info now gives me 8.06MB as expected. It also stay less time in the GPU (about 1/5 of 0.01 second). So from what you say there is no way to get rid of the peaking right?

Comment: nothing is free, you have to expect transients in memory, cpu usage, network traffic ... etc. The point is, if this 'peak' only affects your aesthetic judgement of 'performance', but the app is useable in all respects, don't go chasing ghosts. By switching to pvr you improved many latencies, but the visual quality could be impacted in rare circumstances. Just keep an eye for artefacts, and if they show up, use texture packer to distance your sprites by 2 pixels or so.

Comment: Thanks. Will try not to chease ghosts :). This already helps me a lot as I didn't fully understand why there was twice the memory needed being allocated, and now I have a sound explanation. I tried to use pvr.ccz VS pvr.gz and noticed that the memory peak is higher in pvr.gz (17MB vs 10MB). Is this due to unzipping cost? I am tempted to use only pvr.ccz format but was wondering if pvr.gz has other advantages or if pvr.ccz is simply better :).

Comment: well, i use (instead of texture packer) the pvrtool of Apple and gz (with build scripts) simply because the compression is much improved for my type of texture, it keeps my apps at manageable size. I use texture packer to export as png and convert that to pvr.gz, change the texture file name in the plist and voila.

Comment: Thanks. Lots of things I need to discover. SO suggests me to stop and avoid extended discussions so will do this, but am very curious in learning and understanding what are the compression reasons (I read in some of Steffen's blogs that there are tools to reduce the PNG size by 20/30% but for now my first goal is to avoid the crashes). For now I will try to reduce/remove the crashes by using pvr.ccz files, it should help. Then I will look into gz and file size (there are some scenes where I have 2/3 spritesheets and an mp3 file plus some caf files and that's about 35/40 MB of real memor)