# Why texture cache is not reflected in Live Bytes of Allocations

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit, instruments

I am working on memory measurement of a little cocos2d demo, the demo's task is to add one png image into cocos2d texture cache, the monitors I use are Allocations and Activity Monitor in Instruments.

The test device is ipod touch4.

In order to find the relationship between app's memory and live bytes of allocations, I design two test scenarios.

**The first scenario** is to add texture into cache, and **remove it immediately**. Test Code is below:

> CCTextureCache* cache = [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache];
>
> CCTexture2D* tex = [cache addImage:@"textureatlas_RGBA8888.png"];
>
> [cache removeTexture:tex];

**The second scenario** is to add texture into cache, **but leave it in cache**. Test Code is below:

> CCTextureCache* cache = [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache];
>
> CCTexture2D* tex = [cache addImage:@"textureatlas_RGBA8888.png"];

The size of png file is 270KB, and it has 1024 * 1024 size with 32-bit colour depth, its texture will take up 1024 * 1024 * 4 bytes (32 bits) = 4096 KB in cache.

Test Results are following:

**The first scenario's result:**

[image]

The live bytes will raise to **6.16MB** during adding image into cache, in a while, it will return back to a little more than **2.08MB**.

Until the app finish all operations, the level of live bytes will keep stable. At this time, the real mem in Activity Monitor is **11.61MB**.

**The second scenario's result:**

[image]

The graph of the second test is similar as the first one, however, when the live bytes is stable, the real men is **15.62MB**.

**My first question is:**

**Why the graphs are almost same** even I don't remove texture in cache in the second scenario? doesn't the Allocations consider the texture as live bytes in memory?

**The second question is:**

As I learned from this article:  How to optimize memory usage and bundle size of a Cocos2D app (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/), since the png file will be converted to UIImage firstly, and then add to texture cache, one 1024*1024 texture use 4MB of memory, while loading **it will use 8MB of memory for a short time**, **why I cannot observe it** in the tracking graph of Allocations?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: read a bit about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560405/memory-warnings-in-cocos2d-box2d-apps-on-device-iphone-ipad/14564610#14564610